# Recursive loop in java to create tree structure in jsp page

Tags: jsf, loops, recursion, iteration, recursive-query

I used **tomahawk tree2** component to display directory structure in a JSP page. I have maintained parent and child folder relationship in a database table. Example DB table looks as below.
[image: Where field values represents folder ID's]

When i pass 7 as PARENT_FOLDER_ID to the table i get 87 and 587 as it's sub-folders. Again 87 and 587 contains 6067 and 12704 as their sub-folders. This example only has 2 level relationship.

I need to traverse this relationship until **last sub-folder(Which doesn't contains folders.From the example 2117, 2177, 2312, 2379, 6067, 12704 are last folders.).** How to achieve this traversing process in java. Please help me to find the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Table field values are actually folder-Id's they references to the folders details defined in **folder table**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recursive approach:**

```
public void processChilds(int parentID) {
List childs=selectChilds(parentID);//call method which return list of sub folders of the parameter
for(int i=0;i<childs.size();i++) {
    processChilds(childs.get(i));//call processChilds() for each child
    }
}
```

And Implement the selectChilds(int parentID) as your requirement and that must return list of sub folders.